# Problem to start sqlldr with parfile=parfile.par

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

If have installed Oracle Client 21.11 under Ubuntu. Sqlplus is working fine so far. Only when I try to use   `sqlldr` in combination with  parfile it is not working.
when I call

```
sqlldr user.../pw...@ORCLPDB1 parfile=parfile.par
```

I got the follwing

```
SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Sep 23 17:07:40 2023
Version 21.11.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Direct
```

No error-message and nothing happen

If I only enter `sqlldr user.../pw...@ORCLPDB1` without `parfile=` 
I got  control = and I enter my control-file

```
control = /t/cdp/cdp7/sp3b/data/out/mandant-201/tmp/KEY_0_00020230923122819.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Sep 23 17:19:14 2023
Version 21.11.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

Table KEY_0_000XMLF:
  119 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  KEY_0_00020230923122819.log
for more information about the load.
```

I can upload the file without any problem.

Has somebody a idea why sqlldr is not taking the   parfile  ?
What could be the error?

Comment: Why you haven't posted your parfile's content here?

Comment: What's in your parfile ?